# What does ' sudo rm -rf /* ' do?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, root-filesystem

I ran this command on `Fedora`, which I anyway wanted to uninstall, so I decided to check out this command: `sudo rm -rf /*` just for fun. As soon as I ran this command, the GUI stopped working and patches of black started appearing, I thought the work was done, and did a forced shutdown.
[By the way, I was multibooting Windows 10, Linux Mint, Garuda Linux & Fedora]

When I rebooted, I was expecting Garuda Linux's Grub to show up, but nothing happened and DELL's Support Assist showed up. Then I learned from the BIOS, that the EFI partition was completely erased, which makes sense as it was the `/boot/efi` directory in Fedora.
Then I had to go through the all the recovery stuff to get my OSs booting again.

I was worried that, like the EFI partition, which was mounted to Fedora was completely erased, all my Data partitions would also be erased with the command.
But when I checked out after getting every thing right, every thing was saved. And even the Fedora partition had some space used.

I then formatted the Fedora partition from g-parted of Garuda Linux.

Now I wonder what exactly does the command: `sudo rm -rf /*` really does, just to check I didn't lose any other data.

Comment: "I thought the work was done, and did a forced shutdown" – Possibly it wasn't done and you were lucky to break it early enough for (some of) your data to survive.

Comment: Related (almost-dupes): [How far can you go with rm -rf / as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19547) [Can someone explain what this command does?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227343) [Does Linux allow executing the "rm -rf / " command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134018)

Comment: I wonder what makes someone test something like that without knowing what it does. Evil friends? Destructive mood? Difficult childhood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo rm -rf /*` (`-r` means to remove directories and their contents recursively and `-f` to ignore nonexistent files and arguments and never prompt for confirmation and `/*` just expands to everything in `/`) removes everything in `/` and as you found out with `/boot/efi` this also includes mounted filesystems. The reasons why some data was not removed can be:

1. Partitions from your other distributions/operating systems were not mounted, `rm` can't remove data from unmounted devices/filesystems.
2. They were mounted as read only.
3. As Kamil pointed out, you could stop the recursive remove by the force shutdown in time for some data to survive.

As for why the Fedora had some space used, it depends on how you checked it. Even empty filesystem has some space used (metadata, filesystem reserve etc.) and for example GParted will show this but that doesn't necessary mean some data survived.

Comment: So, I can conclude that the command: 'sudo rm -rf /*' erases every thing in the root partition, including data in the mounted partitions? And one should never use it!

Comment: Yes. You can use it if you really want to remove everything, but there are better tools for that.

Comment: @AustinRojers "Everything" may be more than you think. In some circumstances [`rm -rf` can brick hardware](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2402).

Comment: Actually it won't remove files or folders in the root folder which start with a dot, but that's quite theoretically.

Comment: I believe `rf -r` invokes `/bin/rm` recursively (although I have not seen this tried since Solaris (SunOS 1.9 or so): maybe Linux is smarter). In SunOS, it would shoot itself in the foot during /bin, which is conveniently early in the alphabet. You might still have `sh` and `tar` to restore a backup (assuming you still had a job).

Answer (score -1):

Oversimplify: sudo rm -rf /* will remove all the important files from your OS to boot, work normally. It basically same with delete system32 in Windows.

Comment: No... it isn't the same as `delete system32` at all - which is *relatively* limited in its scope. It will actually attempt to delete the entire contents of the root file system (`/`).

Comment: No, `rm -rf /` and `rm -rf /*` removes *everything* in the root directory, so the equivalent command on Windows would be a command that deletes everything in the C drive, not just system32. `rd C:\ /s /q` or any of its variants.